# Static Routes Problem with Network Plan on Ubuntu 18.04 Azure VM

Tags: networking

I have a Azure Ubnuntu VM with some docker containers.

Problem: The VM does not know the route to one of my networks\ docker interface overlaps with my LAN Subnet.
My LAN is 172.28.0.0\16 and its route should be 10.3.0.1

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         10.3.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.3.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
168.63.129.16   10.3.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
169.254.169.254 10.3.0.1        255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.28.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-828c78b615e2
172.29.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 br-adff3a5cad70
```

I tried adding a static route with netplan and apply it -with no effect -after rebooting - the VM simply resets the netplan config to default.

Netplan config default:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 100
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                driver: hv_netvsc
                macaddress: 00:22:48:9a:d1:4e
            set-name: eth0
    version: 2
```

Anybody have an idea if I am going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, it looks like you're trying to work with the correct file.  documentation as per https://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/adding-persistent-static-routes-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-higher-using-netplan/

I'd suggest that your netplan configuration looks more like the following:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
                route-metric: 100
            dhcp6: false
            match:
                driver: hv_netvsc
                macaddress: 00:22:48:9a:d1:4e
            set-name: eth0
            routes:
                - to: 172.28.0.0/16
                  via: 10.3.0.1
    version: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Suggestion Jad

It seems I was indeed on the wrong path.

I was able to mitigate the conflict with the default network created by my docker config.

The original file is: docker-compose.yml   - this cannot be changed - you have to create a new file:

docker-compose.override.yml

The changes from the override file are merged with the original file.

I used the below in the override file to move away from the 172 -> 173 which opened up my 172 Local Lan to the default GW:

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 173.28.0.0/16
```

I then also had to remove the old docker network with:

sudo docker network rm "id-of-nw"

The ID can be retrieved with the combination of:

sudo docker network ls

and

route

Well -this is my first experience with docker and Im glad im out of this rabbit hole. Hope this helps someone save some time